# How to split a very large python file?

Tags: python

I am using and maintaining a python script allowing to automatize compilation, execution and performances analysis of some particular applications. The script was quite simple when I created it (it only provided the compilation option) but is now very large (2100 lines, not optimized I agree), quite complex and providing many many different command line options (managing the arguments with argparse is a nightmare, and I am not able to do what I need exactly)

To simplify this, I am planning to split it in several scripts:

- compile.py
- run.py
- analyse.py

These three scripts will need to access to share functions, classes and constants. Regarding this constraint, my question is what is the pyhtonic way to handle this ?

Comment: I don't think there is any python specific way to look at this. It's just a big-ol refactoring task :) As @musically_ut said, locate shared functions or even duplicated logic and place it in a separate module to be included as necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the shared code in separate files and then `import` the file as a module in each script which needs it. To see how the module system in Python works, see [the modules documentation for Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) or [the documentation on modules for Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html), depending on which version of Python you are writing code in.